# SQL fill nan with last observed value

Tags: sql, window-functions

Write SQL query that fills Value column NaNs with last known value. SQLite

| client_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14.04.2020 | 10000 |
| 1 | 15.04.2020 | 5000 |
| 1 | 16.04.2020 | NaN |
| 1 | 17.04.2020 | NaN |
| 1 | 18.04.2020 | NaN |
| 2 | 14.04.2020 | 250000 |
| 2 | 15.04.2020 | 250000 |
| 2 | 16.04.2020 | 230000 |
| 2 | 17.04.2020 | 230000 |
| 2 | 18.04.2020 | 225000 |
| 3 | 14.04.2020 | 50000 |
| 3 | 15.04.2020 | NaN |
| 3 | 16.04.2020 | NaN |

I'm thinking about window functions, but don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from the use of `'NaN'` that you are using Postgres.

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't support the `IGNORES NULL` option on window functions.  One method assigns a group to the numbers and then imputes the value for the group:

```
select t.*,
       max(nullif(value, 'NaN')) over (partition by grp) as imputed_value
from (select t.*,
             count(value) filter (where value <> 'NaN') over (partition by client_id order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

It is also possible to do this without a subquery using arrays, but the expression is rather complex:

```
select t.*,
       (array_remove(array_agg(value)over (partition by client_id order by date), 'NaN'))[cardinality(array_remove(array_agg(value)over (partition by client_id order by date), 'NaN'))]
from t;
```

Or using a lateral join:

```
select t.*, t2.value as imputed_value
from t cross join lateral
     (select t2.value
      from t t2
      where t2.client_id = t.client_id and
            t2.date <= t.date and
            t2.value <> 'NaN'
      order by t2.date desc
      limit 1
     ) t2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3fbe976a56eca837cf4132d2380835d0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Nice. But first method doing it wrong when you add more than one client_id. Also, I use SQLite for this task, not Postgres, I forgot to say it.